# Solving A Certain Diophantine Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am stuck on finding the solution of the Diophantine equation:

$d(2^{k+1}-1)-b^2(2^{k+1}-2)=1$.

where $k\geq 1$ and $b^2>d$ for $b$ an odd composite integer.

Is there a solution to this Diophantine equation? If so, what are they and how can I find it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks sir @JoseArnaldoDris it is more convenient to see the solution from your given form ..

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment, as it contained an (elementary) error.

As I had previously noted, your equation can be rewritten as
$$(b^2 - d)(2^{k+1} - 1) = b^2 - 1$$
from which it follows that
$$2^{k+1} - 1 = \frac{b^2 - 1}{b^2 - d} = 1 + \frac{d - 1}{b^2 - d}.$$

Comment: Now, note that $d > 1$, because if $d = 1$, then it would follow that $k = 0$, contradicting $k \geq 1$.  Additionally, we have the divisibility constraints $(b^2 - d) \mid (b^2 - 1)$ and $(b^2 - d) \mid (d - 1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Old answer revised with new information.)*

Given,

$$d(2^{k+1}-1)-b^2(2^{k+1}-2)=1$$

There are solutions for **all** $k$. It is best to simplify with $k=p-1$ to get $\color{brown}{M_p = 2^p-1}$. Hence,

$$d(M_p)-b^2(M_p-1)=1\tag1$$

---

**I. Family 1:** The two general solns in the old answer can be combined into one. For any $p$, there is an infinite number of positive integer $b,d$ that solves $(1)$. For *integer* $n$.

$$b = M_p n \pm 1$$

$$d = (M_p)(M_p-1)n^2\pm2(M_p-1)n+1$$

**II. Family 2:** But there are additional parametric solutions for *even* $p$,

$$b = M_p n \pm  2\,^{p/2}$$

$$d = (M_p)(M_p-1)n^2\pm 2\cdot2\,^{p/2}(M_p-1)n+M_p$$

---

One may ask, "Using **integer** $n$, does this give all the solutions?". If $M_p$ is composite, the answer is no. For example, for $p=23$, the smallest non-family solution is,

$$b = M_{23}n+1 = 3034178,\quad\text{where}\;n=17/47 $$

However, if $M_p>3$ is a *Mersenne prime*, for $p = 3,5,7,13,17,19,\dots$ then *it seems $b = M_p n \pm 1$ is the complete solution.* (I tested $b<10^6$ and there were no non-family solutions for those $p$.)

**P.S.** These families were found using *Mathematica* and some intuitive guessing.

Comment: Are these all the solutions, @TitoPiezasIII?

Comment: Thanks Tito, I know that you are correct, how did you find these solutions and just like @JoseArnaldoDris said are these all the solutions?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris: I generalized my answer. If $M_p = 2^p-1$ is composite, then there are other solutions. However, if $M_p$ is a Mersenne prime, then it seems **Family 1** gives the complete solution.

Comment: @JrAntalan: I used _Mathematica_. For numerical mathematics, some computing power normally comes in handy to see trends.

Comment: I see, thanks @TitoPiezasIII.

Comment: Tito I will leave a comment here if I have questions. Thanks